# Question on jpa joined table inheritance

Tags: jpa

The 'DiscriminatorColumn' annotation isn't creating any column in my parent entity. Where am I going wrong ?

Here's my code

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,length=20)
public class WorkUnit extends BaseEntityClass implements Serializable{

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="G")
@Table(name="Group_")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public class Group extends WorkUnit implements Serializable{
```

Comment: What was your solution, did you find one?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@MappedSuperclass` instead of @Entity on your abstract `WorkUnit` class.

Comment: Hi. @MappedSuperclass doesn't create a separate table for WorkUnit; But I would like one.